# @Inject constructor with parameters

Tags: dagger-2

I saw a method of using `@inject` annotation with parameter constructor. I found no use in `@module` in all parts of the project. I don't understand how this code injects or provides parameters in the constructor.

Can you help me analyze it? 
Where is the datamanager provided?

In the whole project, `@module` + `@provide` is not used to provide datamanager. I only know that `@inject` can only annotate the parameterless constructor. I don't know where to instantiate the parameterless datamanager object. Thank you for your help

application:

```
 public class Scallop extends Application {
        private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                    .build();
        }

        public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() { 
            return applicationComponent;
        }
    }
```

application module:

````
    @Module
    public class ApplicationModule {
        private Scallop application;

        public ApplicationModule(Scallop application) { // 提供类的构造器，传入Applicaton
            this.application = application;
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        Application provideApplication() { 
            return application;
        }

        @Provides
        @ApplicationContext
        Context provideContext() { 
            return application;
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            return retrofit;
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        GankIOService provideGankIOService(Retrofit retrofit) { 
            return retrofit.create(GankIOService.class);
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
        Application getApplication();  

        DataManager getDataManager();
    }
```
````

one class:

```
   @Singleton
    public class DataManager {
        private GankIOService gankIOService;
        private PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

        @Inject
        public DataManager(GankIOService gankIOService, PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper) {
            this.gankIOService = gankIOService;
            this.preferencesHelper = preferencesHelper;
        }
    }
```

fragment module:

````
    @FragmentScope
    @Component(modules = FragmentModule.class, dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)
    public interface FragmentComponent {  
        void inject(HomeFragment homeFragment);

        void inject(GanHuoPageFragment pageFragment);

        void inject(XianDuFragment xianDuFragment);

        void inject(XianDuPageFragment xianDuPageFragment);

        void inject(PicturesFragment picturesFragment);

        void inject(MoreFragment moreFragment);
    }

    @FragmentScope
    @Documented
    @Scope
    @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface FragmentScope {
    }

   ```
````

here  Can't understand constructor with parameter is `@inject`

```
     public class GanHuoPagePresenter extends BasePresenter<GanHuoPageContract.View>
            implements GanHuoPageContract.Presenter {
        private DataManager dataManager;
        private Disposable disposable;

        @Inject
        public GanHuoPagePresenter(DataManager dataManager) { // here here
            this.dataManager = dataManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void detachView() {
            super.detachView();
            if (disposable != null) {
                disposable.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void getGanHuo(String category, final int page) {
            final List<GanHuo> ganHuoList = new ArrayList<>();
            Observable<BaseResponse<GanHuo>> observable = dataManager.getGanHuo(category, page);
            disposable = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .concatMap(new Function<BaseResponse<GanHuo>, ObservableSource<GanHuo>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<GanHuo> apply(@NonNull BaseResponse<GanHuo> ganHuoBaseResponse)
                        throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(ganHuoBaseResponse.getResults());
                }
            }).filter(new Predicate<GanHuo>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull GanHuo ganHuo) throws Exception {
                    return !ganHuo.getType().equals("福利");
                }
            }).subscribe(new Consumer<GanHuo>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(GanHuo ganHuo) throws Exception {
                    ganHuoList.add(ganHuo);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    getView().showError(throwable.getMessage());
                }
            }, new Action() {
                @Override`enter code here`
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    getView().showList(ganHuoList, page);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is how it is used in V in MVP mode：

`@Inject GanHuoPagePresenter presenter`

Answer (score 0):

That's [**constructor injection**](https://dagger.dev/users-guide.html#declaring-dependencies). By marking a constructor with `@Inject` Dagger knows about the object and can create it when needed. There's no need for modules, e.g. the following is a valid Dagger setup to create some `Foo`.

```
public class Foo {
    @Inject
    public Foo() {}
}

@Component
interface MyComponent {
    Foo getFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not true that `@Inject` can only annotate the parameterless constructor. From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)

> Injectable constructors are annotated with @Inject and accept zero or more dependencies as arguments.

I found "your" project on [Github](https://github.com/brusewu/New-App) so let's see where dependencies for GanHuoPagePresenter come from.

```
@Inject
public GanHuoPagePresenter(DataManager dataManager) {
    this.dataManager = dataManager;
}

@Inject
public DataManager(GankIOService gankIOService,PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper){
// gankIOService is provided by ApplicationModule and preferencesHelper uses constructor injection
    this.gankIOService = gankIOService;
    this.preferencesHelper = preferencesHelper;
}

@Inject
public PreferencesHelper(@ApplicationContext Context context){
// context is provided again by ApplicationModule
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```